# How to insert any element after a certain element with jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have form and there is 10 text boxes. now i want to insert a dropdown or combo after 7th text box mean at eight position. how can i do it with jquery. any help with code snippet......or any hind. i know there is `append() & prepend()` function is there but with the help of above two function i can not insert any dropdown at certain position. i search google and found few hint like.

```
<div class="link">
       <input id="textBox" class="link" type="text" value="Skriv länk" />
       <br />
 </div>

does it work by jquery

$("#textBox").after("<p>Hello</p>");

$("input").after("<p>Hello</p>");

$("<p>Hello</p>").insertAfter("input");
```

what code i need to write to add a dropdown after textbox in 7th position? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `eq()`

```
$("input").eq(6).after("<p>Your dropdown</p>");
```

**DEMO** `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/64PaN/

Answer (score 2):

Try using **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to get the position

```
$('input').eq(6).after('<p>Hello</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ID (or anything else to identify it) of the 7th text box, you can use .after() anyway...

```
$("#textBox7").after(/* new element */);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/after/ for more information. The documentation of jQuery is really good written

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<select><option value='test'>test</option></select>").insertAfter($(".link input:nth-child(7)"));
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/dQgCQ/

Comment: yes you can do it :) you must specify class if there is other div with inputs and you don't want to make operations on them :)